# Adding pagination to my theme

Tags: widgets, pagination

I would like to add a pagination to my wordpress theme. However, for me it is not so easy because my theme is built from the plugin "*AT Posts Column*", which displays the latest posts on the main page. I would like to add pagination to this plugin :).

I tried to insert a pagination plugin and paste the code for displaying at the end in the file below. It is true that the pagination appeared, but when I was going to the next page, only the link changed at www.website.com/page/2. Please help :).

My website is http://consolezone.pl

Plugin file "*AT Posts Column*":

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom columns of category with various options
 *
 * @package Acme Themes
 * @subpackage SuperNews
 */
if ( ! class_exists( 'Supernews_posts_col' ) ) {
    /**
     * Class for adding widget
     *
     *  @package Acme Themes
     * @subpackage SuperNews_posts_col
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    class Supernews_posts_col extends WP_Widget {

        /*defaults values for fields*/
        private $defaults = array(
            'supernews_cat_title' => '',
            'supernews_cat' => -1,
            'supernews_enable_posts_featured' => 1,
            'supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout' => 'large',
            'supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout' => 'large'
        );

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(
            /*Base ID of your widget*/
                'supernews_posts_col',
                /*Widget name will appear in UI*/
                __('AT Posts Column', 'supernews'),
                /*Widget description*/
                array( 'description' => __( 'Show posts from selected category', 'supernews' ), )
            );
        }

        /*Widget Backend*/
        public function form( $instance ) {
            $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $this->defaults);
            $supernews_col_posts_title = esc_attr( $instance['supernews_cat_title'] );
            $supernews_selected_cat = esc_attr( $instance['supernews_cat'] );
            $supernews_enable_posts_featured = esc_attr( $instance['supernews_enable_posts_featured'] );
            /*first featured image*/
            $supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout = $instance['supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout'];

            /*normal featured image*/
            $supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout = $instance['supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout'];

            $choices = supernews_get_image_sizes_options();
           ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'supernews_cat_title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'supernews' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'supernews_cat_title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'supernews_cat_title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $supernews_col_posts_title; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('supernews_cat'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Select Category', 'supernews'); ?></label>
                <?php
                $supernews_dropown_cat = array(
                    'show_option_none'   => __('From Recent Posts','supernews'),
                    'orderby'            => 'name',
                    'order'              => 'asc',
                    'show_count'         => 1,
                    'hide_empty'         => 1,
                    'echo'               => 1,
                    'selected'           => $supernews_selected_cat,
                    'hierarchical'       => 1,
                    'name'               => $this->get_field_name('supernews_cat'),
                    'id'                 => $this->get_field_name('supernews_cat'),
                    'class'              => 'widefat',
                    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                    'hide_if_empty'      => false,
                );
                wp_dropdown_categories($supernews_dropown_cat);
                ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'supernews_enable_posts_featured' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'supernews_enable_posts_featured' ); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked( 1, esc_attr( $supernews_enable_posts_featured ), 1 ); ?>/>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'supernews_enable_posts_featured' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Enable Posts Featured' ,'supernews'); ?></label>
                <br />
            </p>
            <p>
                <small><?php esc_html_e( 'Note: Some of the features only work in "Home main content area" due to minimum width in other areas.' ,'supernews'); ?></small>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout' ); ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'First Featured Post Image', 'supernews' ); ?>
                    <br />
                    <small><?php _e( 'Enable First Post Featured to work this layout', 'supernews' ); ?></small>
                </label>
                <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    foreach( $choices as $key => $supernews_column_array ){
                        echo ' <option value="'.$key.'" '.selected( $supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout, $key, 0).'>'.$supernews_column_array.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout' ); ?>">
                    <?php _e( 'Normal Featured Post Image', 'supernews' ); ?>
                    <br />
                    <small><?php _e( 'Enable First Post Featured to work this layout', 'supernews' ); ?></small>
                </label>
                <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    foreach( $choices as $key => $supernews_column_array ){
                        echo ' <option value="'.$key.'" '.selected( $supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout, $key, 0). '>'.$supernews_column_array.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </p>
            <?php
        }

        /**
         * Function to Updating widget replacing old instances with new
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0.0
         *
         * @param array $new_instance new arrays value
         * @param array $old_instance old arrays value
         * @return array
         *
         */
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            $instance = array();
            $instance['supernews_cat_title'] = ( isset( $new_instance['supernews_cat_title'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['supernews_cat_title'] ) : '';
            $instance['supernews_cat'] = ( isset( $new_instance['supernews_cat'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $new_instance['supernews_cat'] ) : '';
            $instance['supernews_enable_posts_featured'] = isset($new_instance['supernews_enable_posts_featured'])? 1 : 0;
            $instance['supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout'] = isset($new_instance['supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout'])? esc_attr( $new_instance['supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout'] ) : 'large';
            $instance['supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout'] = isset($new_instance['supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout'])? esc_attr( $new_instance['supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout'] ) : 'large';

            return $instance;
        }
        /**
         * Function to Creating widget front-end. This is where the action happens
         *
         * @access public
         * @since 1.0.0
         *
         * @param array $args widget setting
         * @param array $instance saved values
         * @return void
         *
         */
        public function widget($args, $instance) {
            if( isset( $args['id'] )){
                $supernews_sidebar_id = $args['id'];
            }
            else{
                $supernews_sidebar_id = 'supernews-home';
            }

            $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $this->defaults);

            $supernews_selected_cat = esc_attr( $instance['supernews_cat'] );

            /*Main title*/
            $supernews_col_posts_title = !empty( $instance['supernews_cat_title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['supernews_cat_title'] ) : get_cat_name($supernews_selected_cat);
            $supernews_col_posts_title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $supernews_col_posts_title, $instance, $this->id_base );

            $supernews_enable_posts_featured = esc_attr( $instance['supernews_enable_posts_featured'] );
            /*first featured post layout*/
            $supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout = esc_attr( $instance['supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout'] );

            /*normal featured image*/
            $supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout = esc_attr( $instance['supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout'] );

            /**
             * Filter the arguments for the Recent Posts widget.
             *
             * @since 1.0.0
             *
             * @see WP_Query
             *
             */
            $supernews_number = 32;
            $supernews_cat_post_args = array(
                'posts_per_page'      => $supernews_number,
                'no_found_rows'       => true,
                'post_status'         => 'publish',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
            );
            if( -1 != $supernews_selected_cat ){
                $supernews_cat_post_args['cat'] = $supernews_selected_cat;
            }

            $supernews_featured_query = new WP_Query($supernews_cat_post_args);

            if ($supernews_featured_query->have_posts()) :
                echo $args['before_widget'];
                if ( !empty( $supernews_col_posts_title ) ){
                    if( -1 != $supernews_selected_cat ){
                        echo "<div class='at-cat-color-wrap-".$supernews_selected_cat."'>";
                    }
                    echo $args['before_title'] . $supernews_col_posts_title . $args['after_title'];

                    if( -1 != $supernews_selected_cat ){
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }

                $supernews_post_col_layout_class = '';
                if( 1 == $supernews_enable_posts_featured ){
                    $supernews_post_col_layout_class = ' featured-posts';
                }
                ?>
                <div class="featured-entries-col <?php echo esc_attr( $supernews_post_col_layout_class ); ?> <?php echo esc_attr( $supernews_sidebar_id ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    $supernews_featured_index = 1;
                    while ( $supernews_featured_query->have_posts() ) :$supernews_featured_query->the_post();
                        $thumb = $supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout;
                        $supernews_list_classes = 'acme-col-2';
                        $supernews_words = 21;
                        if( $supernews_featured_index % 2 == 1 ){
                            echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
                            $supernews_list_classes .= ' odd';
                        }
                        if( 1 == $supernews_enable_posts_featured ){
                            if( $supernews_featured_index <= 2 ){
                                $supernews_list_classes .= ' first-two';
                                $thumb = $supernews_post_col_first_featured_image_layout;
                            }
                            else{
                                $supernews_list_classes .= ' small-posts';
                                $thumb = $supernews_post_col_normal_image_layout;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $supernews_list_classes ); ?>">
                            <!--post thumbnal options-->
                            <div class="post-thumb">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    if( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                                        the_post_thumbnail( $thumb );
                                    else:
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="no-image-widgets">
                                            <?php
                                            the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="caption-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' );
                                            if( !get_the_title() ){
                                                the_date( '', sprintf( '<h2 class="caption-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' );
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    endif;
                                    ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php
                                if(1 == $supernews_enable_posts_featured ){
                                    if(  $supernews_featured_index <= 2  ){
                                        supernews_list_category();
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    supernews_list_category();
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div><!-- .post-thumb-->
                            <div class="post-content">
                                <div class="entry-header">
                                    <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h3>' ); ?>
                                    <div class="entry-meta">
                                        <?php
                                        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
                                            supernews_posted_on();
                                        endif;
                                        supernews_entry_footer();
                                        ?>
                                    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
                                </div><!-- .entry-header -->
                                <?php
                                if(1 == $supernews_enable_posts_featured ){
                                    if(  $supernews_featured_index <= 2  ){
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="entry-content">
                                            <?php
                                            $content = supernews_words_count( get_the_excerpt(), $supernews_words );
                                            echo '<div class="details">'.esc_html( $content ).'</div>';
                                            ?>
                                        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="entry-content">
                                        <?php

                                        $content = supernews_words_count( get_the_excerpt(), $supernews_words );
                                        echo '<div class="details">'.esc_html( $content ).do_shortcode('[post-views]'),'</div>';
                    ?>
                                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                        $supernews_featured_index++;
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $args['after_widget'];
                echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
                // Reset the global $the_post as this query will have stomped on it
                wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
        }
    }
}
if ( ! function_exists( 'supernews_posts_col' ) ) :
    /**
     * Function to Register and load the widget
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @param null
     * @return void
     *
     */
    function supernews_posts_col() {
        register_widget( 'Supernews_posts_col' );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'supernews_posts_col' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$supernews_cat_post_args = array(
                'posts_per_page'      => $supernews_number,
                'no_found_rows'       => true,
                'post_status'         => 'publish',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
            );
```

This is the code where you should add the pagination.

Changing it to:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$supernews_cat_post_args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'      => $supernews_number,
                    'no_found_rows'       => true,
                    'post_status'         => 'publish',
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 
                    'paged' => $paged,
                );
```

May be the key.
First we ask wordpress if it received a query variable to display a page with the first line. If not then the $paged will be 1.
Then we add that to the arguments where the posts are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your help is great! :). Thank you :). 
I downloaded the plugin "*Pagination by BestWebSoft*", then I pasted the code for displaying at the end of the above file and it works magically :D. But I have one more question, because I changed this code to 32:

```
$supernews_number = 32;
```

It was maybe 8. And now the total number of pages appears to me as 29 and the posts are really on 14 pages. Is it possible to somehow remove this dependence :)?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the pagination plugin is counting post numbers differently. Do you have all your posts there(in the 14 pages)?

Comment: Thank you again :). I checked the Wordpress settings and in the reading settings I found an option for displaying the number of posts on the page :). It was 15 and I changed to 32 :D. And now everything works perfectly :). Thank you D. Dan :), and the topic is completely resolved :D.